# apexchart - Get label from database

Tags: apexcharts

I'm not sure as to why the `labels` doesn't work but `series` works when fetching data from the database. I'm using vue and laravel.

Here is my code

```
  <div id="chart">
    <apexchart type="pie" width="380" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"></apexchart>
  </div>
export default {
    data: () => ({
      employees: [],
      series: [],
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          width: 380,
          type: 'pie',
        },
        labels: [],
        responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 80,
          options: {
            chart: {
              width: 200
            },
            legend: {
              position: 'bottom'
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    }),

 methods: {
      kpiProgress () {
        axios.get('/api/employee-kpi-progress', {
          params: { employee_id: this.$store.state.authUser.employee_id }
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.series = response.data
          })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
      },

      kpaInfo () {
        axios.get('/api/employee-kpa-info', {
          params: { employee_id: this.$store.state.authUser.employee_id }
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.chartOptions.labels = response.data
          console.log(this.chartOptions.labels)
          })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
      },
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Made it work. This is a really weird solution since this is my first time directly calling data from a response.

```
kpaInfo () {
  axios.get('/api/employee-kpa-info', {
    params: { employee_id: this.$store.state.authUser.employee_id }
  })
  .then(response => {
    this.chartOptions = {
      labels: response.data,
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
},
```